# modelling staged business process

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, workflows

*imagine*

given a `project` business object and such (simplified) rules:

- it's lifecycle is divided into several `stages of evaluation`;
- stages flow lineary and represent an evaluation chain;
- each stage provides its own `reward value`/algorithm;
- promotion of the project is controlled by other user's decision;
- the resulting reward is assigned to the project's initiator.

*too naive, probably)*

The first thought that comes to my mind is using the `decorator pattern`; because of its structure it looks somewhat applicable. But what if you need to persist additional details provided with the current 'decorated' `state` of project?

*I need an extra behavior on each stage*

I've encountered an article about `jBPM`. I believe it has much in common with `WF`. It is surely has the most of what is needed and at the same time it has (overkill) large infrastructure.

*but can it be designed without incorporating this much complexity?*

What would you suggest?

Comment: I apologize that you were misled but in the future if you feel that your question is better suited at another StackExchange site then please flag a moderator and ask for migration.  On that note I feel this is more appropriate on our site and asked to have your cross posted question on StackOverflow be closed.  Thank you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852939/modelling-staged-business-process

Comment: well, that is good. since my question is quite abstract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I see "process" that spans time, I usually think "state machine". However, one of your requirements says the process is linear, so state machine might be overkill.

It definitely sounds like you have a common interface that describes Stage, with functions like reward(), and a top-level Project that "has a" Stage.

I'm assuming the project runs over an extended time, so you need to be able to save the project state in between events in the project. So Project would have to be persist-able, including the Stage that it's in.

Right off the bat, I see a Project class, Stage interface, and concrete implementations of Stage. And then probably a StageId enum to make it easy to persist the stages.

(Knowing me, I'd probably also define the transitions in a map and implement a really, really simple state machine too. But the simple, linear state machine you have could just be done with if...thens to keep it light.)